# How do I fix materials incorrectly mapping on certain faces?

Tags: materials

I'm new to Blender so this may be fairly obvious. How do I fix the wood texture stretching on the top and bottom surfaces? I would like to keep them oriented the way they are, but have it extend correctly to the other faces.[image: weird image stretching on specific faces]

Comment: The first stage is to mark seams on your object and then UV unwrap it. You can then rotate the faces on the object in the UV editor so that the texture faces in the right direction. Explaining all that is a little complex for this Q&A site so I'd suggest finding one of the many YT tutorials on UV unwrapping such as [this](https://youtu.be/XeBUfMKKZDo)  one.